# (DJANGO - NginX + Unicorn) Deployment not properly working

Tags: django, nginx, deployment, gunicorn, vps

I'm trying to put my django app online on a VPS. I tried following several different tutorials but I could not get it to work...

WHAT I'VE ACHIEVED ALREADY :

- I got DJANGO's DevServ running on my VPS and I was able to browse my app using the VPS' IP address (the static files didn't correctly show up, error 404 104, and I only saw the HTML content without background/css or anything else).
- I got NGINX running on my VPS and I was able to browse to its' default homepage (gunicorn was running at the time but the requests didn't get properly forwarded from NGINX to GUNICORN I believe).
- I got GUNICORN running my app on my VPS with the command below.

Here's how I launch GUNICORN :

```
gunicorn MySite.wsgi:application

[2017-03-12 08:54:47 +0000] [1054] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 19.7.0
[2017-03-12 08:54:47 +0000] [1054] [INFO] Listening at: http://127.0.0.1:8000 (1054)
[2017-03-12 08:54:47 +0000] [1054] [INFO] Using worker: sync
[2017-03-12 08:54:47 +0000] [1059] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 1059
```

And here is my NGINX configuration file ***which I named to match my domain name without the ".eu" (even though right now I'm trying to get it to work with the actual IP address, could this be the issue ?)***. I placed it in "/etc/nginx/sites-available" and made a symlink to the file in "/etc/nginx/sites-enabled" just like the tutorials said to:

```
#IP has been added to ALLOWED_HOSTS in settings.py
server {
    listen      80;
    server_name xxx.xxx.xx.xx;
    charset     utf-8;

    access_log /var/log/nginx/MySite.access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/MySite.error.log;

    #/static/ location as per my configuration and after running "manage.py collectstatic"
    location /static/ {
        alias /home/EveSite/static/;
    }

    # Forward HTTP requests to GUNICORN
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000;
    }
}
```

I'm also having trouble linking my domain name to my VPS' IP but I will leave that for another question.

According to the tutorials I read, everything should be working now but I can only see NGINX's default homepage, no sign of my Django app altho GUNICORN says it is running.

Is there anything I am doing wrong here ? I know I'm probably missing something obvious.

Comment: Please give details. Have you restarted nginx ? Are you seeing anything in your nginx error logs? Are you able to access your django app on port 8000 ?

Comment: I have restarted NGINX and IP:8000 is unreachable. error.log doesn't exist and access.log is empty.

Comment: If I use 0.0.0.0 instead of 127.0.0.1 in GUNICORN I can access my app (effectively bypassing NGINX), but the static files don't load properly and I get unformatted HTML instead of my usual app....

Comment: Did you run collectstatic in order to copy your static files from where nginx could serve it? It also depends on your defined settings.

Comment: Yes I did use collectstatic and all the files are in a /static/ folder at the root of my django project...